# C++ most efficient way of transforming string to hex string

Tags: c++

I have this:

```
std::string TCPMessengerServer::hexStr(unsigned char *data, int len)
{

    constexpr char hexmap[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
        '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

    std::string s(len * 2, ' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[2 * i] = hexmap[(data[i] & 0xF0) >> 4];
        s[2 * i + 1] = hexmap[data[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    return s;
}
```

However, I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.
I'd also like to know if there are easier ways, but if so, what performance trade-offs they present.

Comment: Avoiding the possible dynamic memory allocation will be more efficient for strings over a few chars long.

Comment: Why not use a `std::ostringstream` and the `std::hex` stream manipulator?

Comment: Refer to this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782709/convert-binary-hex-data-to-ascii-equivalent-and-store-in-string/34783244#34783244

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: that would be less efficient, not more.

Comment: Any particular reason for `unsigned char` instead of `char`?

Comment: @101010: they're bytes,.

Comment: 512 bytes will definitely fit into L1 cache, so you might want to hardcode a 256-element lookup table to convert one byte at a time, that will probably be more efficient.

Comment: Shouldn't this discussion be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/? How could someone answer such a question?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Maybe true, but unless this function is called hundred of times each second I'd say go for simplicity.

Comment: To the OP: Why do you want to make this "more efficient"? And what do *you* mean by "more efficient"? Using less CPU? Using less memory? Some other criteria? And have you actually measured that this code is a big bottleneck in your program?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the possible dynamic memory allocation will be more efficient for strings over a few chars long.

A good way to avoid when possible, is to let the caller pass a buffer to place the result in, and to provide a default wrapper using dynamic allocation of a suitable buffer (e.g. a `std::string`, as in your code).

However, unless measurements show this function to be absolutely critical performance-wise, that's most probably just wasted work: it's not something to do as a matter of course.